# Liferay : how to use PDF viewer from web content

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I want to add link to PDF file in web content.

and If i click on that PDF image link it will open up pop up same as document and media.

How to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to access the preview like "document and media" shows or do you want to show the actual pdf document? The later one is dependent on the browser, e.g. if it natively renders pdfs or delegates to an external pdf-viewer. The first one is dependent on the portlet you want to display the preview from: E.g. with webcontent you'd need to do something different than in your own portlets

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something similar to this ?

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Preview+Generation .

Requires imagemagick to be enabled & configured properly. 
You could check document and media portlet **view_file_entry.jsp** to check how it generating preview logic & URL and use same to include for your popup.

Hope this helps !